# Aggregation with limit in hive is not working as expected

Tags: hive

I am trying to count users by channel and need only 3 rows in return.
But it seems like the result is less aggregated than an actual number.
Does anybody know why I cannot use 'group by' and 'limit' at the same time?

```sql
select count(users) as cnt
from user_table
group by channel
limit 3
;
/*
channel cnt
a 39
b 27
c 16
*/
```

```sql
select count(users) as cnt
from user_table
where channel = 'a'
;
/*
channel cnt
a 2057
*/
```

Why do those two queries have different results?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it shows different counts for the same groups... maybe your example is oversimplified, but to make results deterministic `LIMIT` should be used along with `order by`

For example:

```
select count(users) as cnt
from user_table
group by channel
order by cnt desc --top counts first for example
limit 3
```